# Expressions and Filters SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a few things I am struggling with so hopefully I can ask all at once ?

I am using VS 2010 and I think with Vb.net to build reports, I use databases from Sql - I am mainly using matrix tables

1. I have a report that is multiple tables in one but not sure how to set/define to still show the tables that has no data ? So currently if there is a blank one it messes up the full report look ?
2. In another scenario how can I use an expression/custom code to filter out items in one row - in a calculation for example if I only want to sum 3 items of 5 etc
3. How can I work out % of a row or coloumn based on criteria or filters so if total items is 30 and item 1 is 5 the % of will be 17% and all items will total to 100%
4. How can I work out growth of the row/column so if year 1 is 50 and year 2 is 60 the growth/variance will be 20%

Comment: Please open multiple, precise questions and show some code or effort.

Comment: What I have tried for no data =IIF(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = 0 OR Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = "",0,Sum(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value))

Comment: What I have tried for filter = =IIF(Fields!Product_Desc_Review.Value ="Dom Air",Sum(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value),0)

Comment: what I have tried for growth ==SUM((Fields!Current_Amount.Value-Fields!Previous_Amount.Value)/Fields!Previous_Amount.Value) with format as % on text

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the expressions:

```
=IIF(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = 0 
  OR Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = "", 0, Sum(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value))
```

The SUM should be around the **IIF**:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = 0 
      OR Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = "", 0, Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value))
```

The same issue for

```
=IIF(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = 0 
  OR Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = "",0,Sum(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value))
```

Should Be:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = 0 
      OR Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value = "", 0, Fields!Total_Amount__Excl_VAT_.Value))
```

The growth formula looks correct - are you getting a different result than expected?